# Python 3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lot'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a python3 unit test script but it gives me a module not found error when it uses objects from the main scipt and comes across import statements. I don't face this error when I run the main script itself and the code run as expected. The error traceback that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parkingLot_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from source import parking  
  File "/home/stash/Desktop/parking-lot/parking-lot-1.4.2/parking_lot/parking_lot/bin/source/parking.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lot'
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
├── file_inputs.txt
├── parking_lot
├── parkingLot_test.py
├── run_functional_tests
├── setup
└── source
    ├── car.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lot.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── parking.py
```

The code for unit test file **parkingLot_test.py**:

```
import unittest
from source import parking  

class ParkingTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def MakeClass(cls):
        cls.parking = parking.Parking()
        cls.allocated_slot = 1

    def test_a_create_parking_lot(self):
        parking_slots = 6
        self.parking.create_parking_lot(parking_slots)
        self.assertEqual(len(self.parking.slots), parking_slots,
                         msg="Wrong parking lot created")

    def test_b_park(self):
        registration_no = "MH-12-FF-2017"
        colour = "Black"
        self.parking.park(registration_no, colour)
        self.assertFalse(
            self.parking.slots[self.allocated_slot].available, "Park failed.")
        for i in self.parking.slots.values():
            if not i.available and i.car:
                self.assertEqual(i.car.registration_no,
                                 registration_no, "Park failed")
                self.assertEqual(i.car.colour, colour, "Park failed")

    def test_c_leave(self):
        self.parking.leave(self.allocated_slot)
        self.assertTrue(
            self.parking.slots[self.allocated_slot].available, "Leave failed.")

    @classmethod
    def RemoveClass(cls):
        del cls.parking


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The code for the imported file **parking.py**:

```
import lot
import car


class Parking:
    """
    Parking class which has details about parking slots
    as well as operation performed on parking are present here
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.slots = {}

    def create_parking_lot(self, no_of_slots):
        """This method will create parking lot if not present already with given
        number of slots.
        Input: no_of_slots - Integer Type
        """
        no_of_slots = int(no_of_slots)

        if len(self.slots) > 0:
            print("Parking Lot already created")
            return

        if no_of_slots > 0:
            for i in range(1, no_of_slots+1):
                temp_slot = lot.ParkingSlot(slotNum=i,
                                            availability=True)

                self.slots[i] = temp_slot
            print("Created a parking lot with %s slots" % no_of_slots)
        else:
            print("Number of slots provided is incorrect.")
        return

    def get_nearest_available_slot(self):
  ...................
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The folder `source` needs to be added to the import path by either appending it's path to `sys.path` or by putting it in `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @rdas I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lot'`

Comment: I used `sys.path.append("./")` before the  import lot statement and tried running parking.py directly @rdas.

Answer (score 6):

As python 3 doesn't support Implicit relative import. You can use explicit relative import.

Try using the following line instead of **import lot** in **parking.py**

`from . import lot`

Comment: Try running the script using this command `python -m parkingLot_test`

Comment: I get an error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` with you method on the main script and on using `python -m parkingLot_test` the test script seems to be running fine except for some python3 syntax difference errors. So, it seems to be running as expected for Python 2.7

Comment: Information about `__package__` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__) When running a script directly, it doesn't set the `__package__` attribute and so it is set to none. If you run the script using **-m** flag, it tells the interpreter to treat file as a module.

Answer (score 2):

in the same directory level file when you import the one file in another use relative import like

in `parking.py` file importing `lot.py` file as

```
import .log
```

and when import from one directory to lower directory ie importing lot in 
`parkingLot_test.py`, use `from source import lot`

and in the source folder in `__init__.py` file write

```
import .lot
import .parking
```

like this.

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: module 'source.lot' has no attribute '__all__'`

Comment: just remove `__all__ `from `__init__.py`file if you havn't mentioned the `__all__` in  lot.py,

Comment: yes you can write and make changes in `__init__.py` file, i made change in solution , like this write in `__init__.py` file

Comment: I tried youe methid but I get the error `AttributeError: 'ParkingTest' object has no attribute 'parking'`

Comment: `from source.parking import Parking`