# No module named 'portfoliodjango' error on manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

Got this error in django while trying to use manage.py to runserver or migrate or anything using that file. My project name is website and app name is portfolio. Please Help :)

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.virtualenvs\website-o1OcjGMR\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.virtualenvs\website-o1OcjGMR\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.virtualenvs\website-o1OcjGMR\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.virtualenvs\website-o1OcjGMR\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.virtualenvs\website-o1OcjGMR\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'portfoliodjango'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your INSTALLED_APPS, probably you missed a comma when listing `portfolio`

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to find **portfoliodjango** file. You must be importing this file in your project or just misspelled it.

1. See if the file name is correct / it exits.
2. Are you importing from the right location in right way? See if the issue is like this:

=> [Python 3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536673/python-3-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-lot) or

=> [Relative imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)

If these steps doesn't help then kindly provide the information on **portfoliodjango**, like where you have used this name.